# simplify r code for mean & sd then ipsatization calculation

Tags: r, dplyr

Hi for my dissertation I'd hope to do a caculation called ipsatization, basically it's a method for standardizing scores within subject. For each survey instrument(stress,regulation,scs), there are several items. I calculated the overall mean and sd of all item within the same instrument and subtracted the overall mean from individuals scores for each item and then divided the gap by sd(within each scale range).

I just started to use R studio and couldn't think of a way to simplify my code. For now, I'm creating subset for each instrument's item name, and then calculate the mean and sd one after one, following the final calculation.

The output I get is fine,I guess I'd really hope to get some advice on how to cut out the repeated work of my input code because I was doing the same thing for every set of instrument.

Thank you for your time!

In r, I've tried this- data 4 is my original dataset

```
library(dplyr)
#create a new dataset for ipsatized results
data5 <- data4


#create list of item names for three instruments
stress <- c("BES_1", "BES_2", "BES_3", "BES_4", "BES_5") 
reg <- c("Neg_ctrl1","Pos_ctrl1","Neg_use1","Pos_use1") 
scs <- c("Ind_1","Ind_2","Inter_1","Inter_2","Ind_3")

#calculate overall mean and sd within each intrument(this I repeated 3 times for different instruments) 
row_m <- rowMeans(data4[, stress], na.rm = TRUE) 
row_sds <- apply(data4[, stress], 1, sd, na.rm = TRUE)

row_m <- rowMeans(data4[, reg], na.rm = TRUE) 
row_sds <- apply(data4[, reg], 1, sd, na.rm = TRUE)

row_m <- rowMeans(data4[, scs], na.rm = TRUE) 
row_sds <- apply(data4[, scs], 1, sd, na.rm = TRUE)

#proceed to the final calculation 
for (col in stress) { 
data5[, col] <- (data5[, col] - row_m) / row_sds 
}

for (col in reg) { 
data5[, col] <- (data5[, col] - row_m) / row_sds 
}

for (col in scs) { 
data5[, col] <- (data5[, col] - row_m) / row_sds 
}

#for the ease of presenting here, I slice data5 to only first 10 row.
dput(data5)
structure(list(BES_1 = structure(c(-1.65, -1.24, 0.42, -0.42,-0.38, -0.95, -1.98, -0.61, 0.68, 0.47), format.spss = "F40.0", display_width = 11L), 
BES_2 = structure(c(0.27, -1.24, -0.3, -1.15, -0.38, -1.44, 
-0.22, -0.61, -1.35, -0.78), format.spss = "F40.0", display_width = 11L), 
BES_3 = structure(c(0.27, 1.24, 1.15, 0.3, -1.31, 0.54, 0.66, 
-0.61, 0.68, 1.09), format.spss = "F40.0", display_width = 11L), 
BES_4 = structure(c(0.91, 1.24, 1.87, 1.03, 1.46, 1.03, 0.66, 
1.82, 0.68, 1.09), format.spss = "F40.0", display_width = 11L), 
BES_5 = structure(c(0.91, -0.25, 0.42, 2.48, 0.54, 0.54, 
0.66, -0.61, -2.03, 1.09), format.spss = "F40.0", display_width = 11L), 
Neg_ctrl1 = structure(c(0.19, -0.42, -0.15, 1.63, -0.52, 
-0.11, 0.15, 0.12, 0.74, -0.33), format.spss = "F40.0", display_width = 11L), 
Pos_ctrl1 = structure(c(-0.83, 1.43, 0.66, 0.95, 2.8, 1.05, 
-0.45, 0.12, 1.26, 1.95), format.spss = "F40.0", display_width = 11L), 
Neg_use1 = structure(c(-0.83, -0.42, 0.66, -0.43, 0.31, -0.11, 
0.15, 3.05, -0.29, -0.33), format.spss = "F40.0", display_width = 11L), 
Pos_use1 = structure(c(-0.83, -0.42, -0.15, -1.12, -0.52, 
-1.27, -1.06, -0.85, -0.81, -1.09), format.spss = "F40.0", display_width = 11L), 
Ind_1 = structure(c(0.51, 0.28, 0.86, 0.49, 0.38, -0.64, 
0.28, 1.09, -0.47, 0.8), format.spss = "F40.0", display_width = 11L), 
Ind_2 = structure(c(-0.51, 0.84, 0.14, -1.15, -0.97, -0.64, 
-1.1, -0.99, -1.53, 1.56), format.spss = "F40.0", display_width = 11L), 
Inter_1 = structure(c(0.51, 0.84, 0.14, 0.49, 1.06, -1.72, 
0.96, 1.09, 1.11, -0.74), format.spss = "F40.0", display_width = 11L), 
Inter_2 = structure(c(0.51, 0.84, 0.86, 1.04, 1.06, 1.5, 
0.96, 1.09, 1.11, 0.03), format.spss = "F40.0", display_width = 11L), 
Ind_3 = structure(c(-0.51, 0.84, -0.57, -1.15, -0.97, -0.64, 
-1.1, -0.99, -1, -0.74), format.spss = "F40.0", display_width = 11L)), row.names = c(NA,-10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl","data.frame"))
```

Comment: Hi and welcome! Could you edit your question to include (1) the output of `dput(data5)` (it starts with "structure(...)" and (2) your desired output? Good luck!

Comment: Thank you JP for your message. I've added the output using dput. The output I get is fine,I guess. But would hope to get your advice or comments on the code I'm running and see if I'm able to cut out the repeated work of my input, as I was doing the same calculation for every set of instrument then score.

Answer (score 1):

My guess:

```r
library(dplyr)
data4 %>%
  mutate(across(all_of(scs), ~ (.x - mean(.x)) / sd(.x)))
```

Demo with `mtcars`:

```r
head(mtcars)
#                    mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
# Mazda RX4         21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
# Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
# Datsun 710        22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
# Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
# Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
# Valiant           18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1

scs <- c("disp", "mpg")
mtcars %>%
  mutate(across(all_of(scs), ~ (.x - mean(.x)) / sd(.x))) %>%
  head()
#                          mpg cyl        disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
# Mazda RX4          0.1508848   6 -0.57061982 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
# Mazda RX4 Wag      0.1508848   6 -0.57061982 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
# Datsun 710         0.4495434   4 -0.99018209  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
# Hornet 4 Drive     0.2172534   6  0.22009369 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
# Hornet Sportabout -0.2307345   8  1.04308123 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
# Valiant           -0.3302874   6 -0.04616698 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
```

- `across` is analogous to `apply` in that it does "something" for each of the identified columns
- columns are identified here using `all_of(scs)`, meaning all of the columns identified by the character vector `scs`, there are many other ways to identify these columns, see [`?select`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/select.html)
- the "something" is an rlang-style tilde function, where `.x` is the value of the column being worked on; these two are functionally equivalent, and can both be used in the `across` second argument:

  ```
  ~ (.x - mean(.x)) / sd(.x)
  function(z) (z - mean(z)) / sd(z)
  ```